# Can't assign to function call syntax error when trying to subtract variables in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to create a rudimentary stock trading algorithm. One thing included in that algorithm is, after deciding how many of a stock to buy, subtracting the correct amount of money from the user's total. The problem occurs on the line "int(money_data) -= int(round(float(stockamounts[i]) * float(prices[i])))". The syntax error points to "int(money_data). "I hope I explained the problem in a way that makes sense. Thank you for any help.

```
for i in stock_symbols:
  stock_url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" + str(i)
  stock_data = requests.get(stock_url)
  file = open("data.txt", "w")
  file.write(str(stock_data.content))
  file.close()
  file = open("data.txt", "r")
  stock_data = file.read()
  file.close()
  stock_data = re.findall(r'<div id="qwidget_lastsale" class="qwidget-dollar">(.*?)</div>', str(stock_data))

  for i in stock_data:
    print(str(i.strip('$')))
    price = i.strip('$')
    prices.append(price)

stock_amounts = []

print(str(stock_symbols[0]) + " | " + str(round(float(money_amount) / float(prices[0]))))
stock_amounts.append(round(float(money_amount) / float(prices[0])))
for x in range(len(prices)):
  print(str(stock_symbols[x]) + " | " + str(round(float(money_amount) / float(prices[x]))))
  stock_amounts.append(round(float(money_amount) / float(prices[x])))
print(len(stock_amounts))

for i in stock_amounts:
  print(stock_amounts[i])
  int(money_data) -= int(round(float(stock_amounts[i]) * float(prices[i])))
print(money_data)
```

Comment: Do you really need to use int()? In any case int() should not be used on the left hand side of = (or -= ).

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you

> can't assign to [a] function call

#### Why?

Say you have a function f:

```
>>> def f(x);
...     return 3*x+4
```

When you

```
>>> f(4) = 5
```

what do you actually mean? You can't logically explain what should happen in a case like this, because basically (and in this example), that's like saying `16 = 5`, which, I hope you agree, doesn't make sense.

#### "But, I did something different"

Yes, you used a variable in the call and used the `-=` operator.
Still, the `a -= b` operator is short for `a = a-b` (although you *could* overload them to do different stuff), and that's clearly an assignment (even if you overload, it remains an assignment).

#### How do I fix this?

You have two (and a half) possibilities:

- use a normal assignment: just expand to a longer form as in `val = int(val-to_sub)`
- add an extra line `val -= to_sub; val = int(val)` (please actually add an extra line and don't use `;`)
- (1/2) leave the `int()` away. If you are careful to only add, subtract, multiply with or divide through `int`s (or use `//` for divisions), you are sure that the value stays an `int`

Comment: @JacobStein if it worked, you can accept the answer -- the tick at the top-left corner, next to "Why"